# Origine e uso di "Per la quale"

Tags: word-usage, phrase-origin

***"Per la quale"*** viene spesso usata come espressione idiomatica con i seguenti significati:

> - ***(loc. agg. inv.)***
>
>   - (fam.) Di persona, perbene, raccomandabile: *un uomo per la quale; non mi pare tanto per la quale.*
>   - Ben fatto, apprezzabile: *un lavoretto proprio per la quale.*
> - ***(loc. avv.)***
>
>   - (fam.) Egregiamente, in modo soddisfacente: *il compito non è andato troppo per la quale.*

(Hoepli)

Che origine ha questa espressione e perché si usa sempre al femminile?

Comment: "Spesso"? Non ho mai sentito utilizzare **per la quale** con questa accezione nell'italiano corrente.

Comment: Beh..dieri che è un'espessione molto comun, io la sento spesso e la uso spesso. Sentiamo anche il parere di altri, comunque.

Comment: Ci mancherebbe, ma adesso per curiosità, dove vivi? Perché potrebbe essere un regionalismo di cui non sono al corrente. Io sono nato e cresciuto a Torino, ma ho passato tutte le mie estati fino ai 20 anni in Puglia e Calabria.

Comment: O_O   Adesso sono ancora più stupito!!!

Comment: Io l'ho sentita (ma quasi mai usata) soprattutto in accezione negativa ("Non mi sembra tanto per la quale"). Se serve, vivo in Lombardia.

Comment: @writingthesis - concordo, l'accezione negativa è quella forse più usata con espressioni del tipo "*mica tanto per la quale*"  riferito a cose o persone.

Comment: Vivo in Veneto (Verona) e questa è un’espressione che ho sentito piú volte, spessissimo col significato di «a posto con la testa».

Comment: mai sentito in vita mia (Milano).

Comment: Roma: sentita non spessissimo, ma ben comprensibile, soprattutto nell'ultimo senso riportato dal dizionario, e soprattutto al negativo.

Comment: Per me *per la quale* normalmente significa *bene*, nel senso, per esempio, di "oggi non sono molto per la quale", intendendo che sono stanco o nervoso e quindi non ho voglia di essere di essere disturbato con cose frivole.

Comment: Dalle mie parti (Umbria) il significato corrisponde esattamente a quello riportato dal vocabolario. Viene inoltre usato quasi esclusivamente nella sua variante negativa, ossia "non è un tipo per la quale" per indicare una persona poco raccomandabile, dedita ad attività losche.

Comment: Mai sentito questa espressione in vita mia

Answer (score 1):

Probabilmente (ricerca originale) contrazione di "cosa per la quale vale la pena [verbo]". Dato l'accostamento di due modi di dire di cui uno autonomo (vale la pena), questo viene eliso dalla frase e lasciato al contesto culturale. Non l'ho sentito spessissimo (veneto orientale) ma sicuramente in più di qualche occasione.

Sempre probabilmente (sempre ricerca originale), per via della forma generica "cosa/situazione", il modo di dire conserva un genere femminile nel sostantivo sottointeso.